# Как принято называть связанные контейнер и презентационный компонент в React?

Tags: reactjs

Допустим, у меня есть контейнер под названием Cart и он рендерит компонент, но, как его назвать CartComponent?

Comment: Называйте так, чтобы и вам и другим было понятно что содержит в себе файл. Добавлять компонент не обязательно. CartLayout может

Comment: Пока до других далеко) Я в том смысле, что как-то по другому назвать надо, а то рекурсия получиться)

Comment: я уже ответил, как хотите так и называйте, правил нет.